# Ajax Post Value not being passed to php file

Tags: javascript, php

I am having problems passing the variable to the php page.

Here is the code below:

```
var varFirst = 'something'; //string
var varSecond = 'somethingelse'; //string

$.ajax({  
   type: "POST",  
   url: "test.php",  
   data: "first="+ varFirst +"&second="+ varSecond,  
       success: function(){  
          alert('seccesss');

   }
});
```

PHP:

```
$first = $_GET['first']; //This is not being passed here
$second = $_GET['second']; //This is not being passed here

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","mydb"); 

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO mytable (id, first, second) VALUES ('', $first, $second)");

mysqli_close($con);


}
```

I'm I missing something? The actual data is saving to the database BUT $first and $second value is not being passed to the php file.

Comment: You should pass your data as JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the POST type, retrieve it in POST :

```
$first = $_POST['first'];
$second = $_POST['second'];
```

Or change your JQuery call :

```
$.ajax({  
   type: "GET",  
   url: "test.php",  
   data: "first="+ varFirst +"&second="+ varSecond,  
       success: function(){  
          alert('seccesss');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is appening because your are passing data throw `POST` method and try to get with `GET` so change those two lines

```
$first = $_POST['first']; //This is not being passed here
$second = $_POST['second']; //This is not being passed here
```

Or simply change your method to `GET` in your jquery

```
type: "GET"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using type: "POST" in ajax and trying to fetch using $_GET, try

```
$first = $_REQUEST['first']; //This is not being passed here
$second = $_REQUEST['second'];
```

Answer (score 1):

And there is a method to pass data like that

```
$.ajax({  
   type: "POST",  
   url: "test.php",  
   data: {first: varFirst,second: varSecond},  
       success: function(){  
          alert('seccesss');

   }
});
```

And there you can use

```
$_POST['first'];
$_POST['second'];
```

Hope it helps.